# Spark 1.3.1 install failed in MLlib when I run make-distribution.sh in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib

Spark 1.3.1 install failed in MLlib when I run make-distribution.sh in Ubuntu 14.04

- Java -version: `java version "1.7.0_80"
  Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_80-b15)
  Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.80-b11, mixed mode)`
- Scala -version: `Scala code runner version 2.10.4 -- Copyright 2002-2013, LAMP/EPFL`
- Failing message:

```
`

    INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] Building Spark Project ML Library 1.3.2-SNAPSHOT
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [WARNING] The POM for net.sf.opencsv:opencsv:jar:2.3 is invalid, transitive dependencies (if any) will not be available, enable debug logging for more detail
    s
    [INFO] 
    [INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ spark-mllib_2.10 ---
    [INFO] Deleting /home/tongz/project/spark/spark/mllib/target
    [INFO] 
    [INFO] --- maven-enforcer-plugin:1.3.1:enforce (enforce-versions) @ spark-mllib_2.10 ---
    [INFO] 
    [INFO] --- scala-maven-plugin:3.2.0:add-source (eclipse-add-source) @ spark-mllib_2.10 ---
    [INFO] Add Source directory: /home/tongz/project/spark/spark/mllib/src/main/scala
    [INFO] Add Test Source directory: /home/tongz/project/spark/spark/mllib/src/test/scala
    [INFO] 
    [INFO] --- build-helper-maven-plugin:1.8:add-source (add-scala-sources) @ spark-mllib_2.10 ---
    [INFO] Source directory: /home/tongz/project/spark/spark/mllib/src/main/scala added.
    [INFO] 
    [INFO] --- maven-remote-resources-plugin:1.5:process (default) @ spark-mllib_2.10 ---
    [WARNING] Invalid POM for net.sf.opencsv:opencsv:jar:2.3, transitive dependencies (if any) will not be available, enable debug logging for more details
    [WARNING] Invalid project model for artifact [opencsv:net.sf.opencsv:2.3]. It will be ignored by the remote resources Mojo.
    [INFO] 
    [INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ spark-mllib_2.10 ---
    [INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
    [INFO] Copying 26 resources
    [INFO] Copying 3 resources
    [INFO] --- scala-maven-plugin:3.2.0:compile (scala-compile-first) @ spark-mllib_2.10 ---
    [INFO] Using zinc server for incremental compilation
    [INFO] compiler plugin: BasicArtifact(org.scalamacros,paradise_2.10.4,2.0.1,null)
    [info] Compiling 144 Scala sources and 2 Java sources to /home/tongz/project/spark/spark/mllib/target/scala-2.10/classes...
    [error] error while loading , error in opening zip file
    [error] object scala.runtime in compiler mirror not found.
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] Reactor Summary:
    [INFO] 
    [INFO] Spark Project Parent POM .......................... SUCCESS [4.145s]
    [INFO] Spark Project Networking .......................... SUCCESS [11.811s]
    [INFO] Spark Project Shuffle Streaming Service ........... SUCCESS [6.064s]
    [INFO] Spark Project Core ................................ SUCCESS [2:39.458s]
    [INFO] Spark Project Bagel ............................... SUCCESS [5.837s]
    [INFO] Spark Project GraphX .............................. SUCCESS [17.580s]
    [INFO] Spark Project Streaming ........................... SUCCESS [30.898s]
    [INFO] Spark Project Catalyst ............................ SUCCESS [34.868s]
    [INFO] Spark Project SQL ................................. SUCCESS [41.695s]
    [INFO] Spark Project ML Library .......................... FAILURE [0.522s]
    [INFO] Spark Project Tools ............................... SKIPPED
    [INFO] Spark Project Hive ................................ SKIPPED
    [INFO] Spark Project REPL ................................ SKIPPED
    [INFO] Spark Project Assembly ............................ SKIPPED
    [INFO] Spark Project External Twitter .................... SKIPPED
    [INFO] Spark Project External Flume Sink ................. SKIPPED
    [INFO] Spark Project External Flume ...................... SKIPPED
    [INFO] Spark Project External MQTT ....................... SKIPPED
    [INFO] Spark Project External ZeroMQ ..................... SKIPPED
    [INFO] Spark Project External Kafka ...................... SKIPPED
    [INFO] Spark Project Examples ............................ SKIPPED
    [INFO] Spark Project External Kafka Assembly ............. SKIPPED
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] Total time: 5:13.600s
    [INFO] Finished at: Sun May 03 21:23:26 EDT 2015
    [INFO] Final Memory: 41M/499M
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [ERROR] Failed to execute goal net.alchim31.maven:scala-maven-plugin:3.2.0:compile (scala-compile-first) on project spark-mllib_2.10: Execution scala-compile-first of goal net.alchim31.maven:scala-maven-plugin:3.2.0:compile failed. CompileFailed -> [Help 1]
    [ERROR] 
    [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
    [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
    [ERROR] 
    [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
    [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginExecutionException
    [ERROR] 
    [ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
    [ERROR]   mvn  -rf :spark-mllib_2.10

`
```

This is the last few line of error message, if you need I can provide you more.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok wait for 12 hours still no answer! I dig a lot I think I found the answer myself
here are the trick:

`sbt clean clean-files
rm -rf ~/.ivy2 ~/.m2 ~/.sbt`

These 2 lines are the problem

    [error] error while loading , error in opening zip file
    [error] object scala.runtime in compiler mirror not found.

From what I understand I have some scalar or mvn package broken before, it causes this error, I have to remove them. Also it may also because of sbt was old that's why I did clean that.

PS: if you wanna find what packages are broken do follow cli

find ~/.ivy2 ~/.m2 ~/.sbt -name "*.jar" -exec unzip -qqt {} \;